# How a thread service two data sockets (not control sockets) equally?

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets, client-server

Suppose that we have a single-thread application, and it needs to service two clients by writing 1G bytes data to two separate tcp sockets (one socket per client) respectively, in this situcation how can the thread work on the two tasks equally and continually?

I think this problem exists in server applications like Apache, take the Apache Web Server as an example, the Apache sets a max thread limit for itself, say it is MAX_THREADS, and if there  are (MAX_THREADS + 1) outstanding requests and sockets there which means at least one thread must handle two sockets equally. Then how would apache handle this situation?

Steve

Comment: Read http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when we want to handle several sockets in a single threaded application then  one of the following system calls are generally used

> select (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28Unix%29)
>
> poll (http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll)
>
> epoll (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoll)

More on these calls can be found in the man pages.

the general idea is to make the single thread not get blocked waiting to get a resource and periodically check if data is available to send or receive

Comment: Also google for the `C10K problem` (hence prefer `poll` to `select`)